# Debugging an AndEngine game that randomly crashes on startup

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine, adt

I am following an [AndEngine tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12762/creating-a-sprite-and-scene-andengine/) and have gotten to the point where there is something on the screen.

I decide to export it as an apk, copy it onto my phone and install it manually from there (thinking this would simulate someone downloading it from the play store or otherwise). However, when I start the game, it immediately crashes.

I try starting again, and it works fine. Repeating a couple times, it still works normally.

I uninstall and re-install the app to see if maybe that might be the problem, and it crashed again when I start it for the first time!

I repeat the uninstall/re-install, but this time the crash didn't occur.

How do I debug this problem? I can't seem to reproduce it when I install it through eclipse, and this doesn't happen all the time either, so I'm not sure what conditions must be met in order for the app to crash.

It would be terrible if someone downloaded the game and it crashed.

Comment: How does the logcat look like

Comment: @dcanh121 I copied the apk to my SD card and I'm installing it manually through a file explorer, so I disconnected the USB. Can I install it through my phone while the debugger is attached?

Comment: @dcanh121 I'm using ES file explorer and when the USB is attached the SD card is unmounted. I've only been able to reproduce the issue when I install the application through the file explorer.

Comment: Since you say that, try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.potente.apk.installer

Comment: @dcanh121 What would the difference be between that and the way I'm going now? Would it provide a way to debug the issue (for example, allowing me to install the app via phone while having the logger attached). Note that when I say "installing through my phone" I don't mean testing my app on my phone via eclipse (as opposed to an emulator), if there was any confusion there.

Comment: It wouldn't make much of a difference. but since you said you're having this issue specifically using explorer app, I suggested you to try something else. you could also install the exported apk using adb command. By exported I mean, you signed the apk with a release certificate.

Comment: @dcanh121 that's true, I should try different installation methods because it might just be the explore app doing something wrong. Or get a play store account and just see if it crashes after it's installed.